# Django accessing dynamic form value from html page to views

Tags: python, html, django, forms, jinja2

Html code
input type="text" name="a" value="{{abc}}" disabled

views.py
x=request.POST['a']

I am trying to access html textbox value name=a and which has a dynamic value

It give MultiValueDictKey error

So i change views.py code to
x=request.POST.get('a')

And i tried to print x it prints None instead of the value in textbox

Please help

Comment: can you please share your views.py and template

Comment: and your url.py please..

Comment: HTML Page '''<form action="register" method="POST">
                      {% csrf_token %} 
                                <input type="text" name="a" value="{{abc}}">
                                <input type="submit"> </form>'''
 Views.py '''def register(request):
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        x = request.POST.get("a")
            add_user = User.objects.create_user(username=x)
            add_user.save()
            messages.info(request, "User Created")
            return render(request, "index.htm")'''

Comment: in this  ' value="{{abc}}"  '    remove {{ }}

Answer (score 1):

**views.py**

```
def your_function(request):
    text_input = request.POST.get('a')
```

This is correct answer! BUT!

*disabled* flag inside input tag means that: **THIS FIELD WILL NOT BE SUBMITTED WITH FORM**

Comment: I removed "disabled" and instead of "disabled" i put "readonly" and it worked

Comment: This is good question actually, because many developers don't know that disabled will not be sended.